# Clear Windows 7 network computer names cache

Tags: windows-7, hostname

Recently we switched the names of two computers in a small network. Let's say the first was visible as `one` on the network and the other was `two`. We just switched their names. The Windows XP machines on the network have picked up the change but there is one Windows 7 PC that has not updated its computer name to computer IP address mapping.

Is there a way in Windows 7 to clear or refresh the record of the cached names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Command Prompt run `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: Well, the problem was that for some reason the computer name to ip address mapping was hardcoded in the "System32\drivers\etc\hosts" file =) Thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

**You need to clear both the DNS and NetBIOS name caches.** According to the Microsoft support article [Microsoft TCP/IP Host Name Resolution Order](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172218) both are used in Windows to cache hostnames.

Do this from an elevated Command Prompt by running these two commands:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
nbtstat -R
```

(The `-R` is case-sensitive)

If you're still having trouble, double-check the Windows Hosts file to ensure a static name mapping hasn't been configured.  On Windows NT and above the hosts file is located in the folder `%Systemroot%\System32\Drivers\Etc` and is named **hosts** (without a file extension).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, do you have AD in your network? Anyway, try to disable Microsoft Computer Browser Service service in win7. You must wait more than 15 min to see effect.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, but here is something I tried, and it worked:

- open services.msc on the affected PC
- find the Computer Browser service
- Stop the service
- Refresh File Browser with the network location open
- Start the Computer Browser service

Your new name should appear.